# Filter unique matches of multiple columns in dataframe with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to pandas and I've been trying multiple solutions for this problem using `dataframe.merge` and `lambda` logic but I haven't been able to find an solution that consistently results with what I'm looking for.
After filtering some data using

```
df = df.groupby(['0', '1']).size()
df = df.to_frame(name='2').reset_index()
```

I obtain the following table, the first two columns represent starting and ending points respectively and the third represent the number of times it repeated before the `groupby`:

```
0   1   2
a   d   8
b   h   7
c   f   3
c   e   3
d   a   2
b   b   2
e   c   1
f   c   1
g   i   1
h   b   1
i   g   1
```

I need to consider both start -> end and end -> start points as the same, meaning that the following dataframe:

```
0   1   2
a   d   8
d   a   2
```

should end looking like this:

```
0   1   2
a   d   10
```

And back to the original table, that one should end looking like this:

```
0   1   2
a   d   10
b   h   8
c   f   4
c   e   4
b   b   2
g   i   2
```

I'm fairly sure this should be an easy solution but for the life of me I just can't pinpoint the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df1 = df[['0', '1']].apply(sorted, 1, result_type = "expand").rename(columns = {0:'col1', 1:'col2'})
    
result = df.groupby([df1.col1, df1.col2]).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Hey! This works too! It was also easier to understand to me (or at least I'd like to think that), also just like Anderson's answer, this wouldn't filter if there was any `int` along with the `str` entries. I could easily fix it by adding `astype(str)` like so: `df1 = result_co[['Connector 1', 'Connector 2']].astype(str).apply(sorted, 1, result_type="expand").rename(columns={0: 'col1', 1: 'col2'})`

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `apply` to sort the values in the columns, then do another `groupby`(Note that your column names may differ, my `df` was made using `pd.read_clipboard()`)

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df[['0','1']]=df[['0','1']].apply(lambda x:sorted(x),axis=1).tolist()

df

    0   1   2
0   a   d   8
1   b   h   7
2   c   f   3
3   c   e   3
4   a   d   2
5   b   b   2
6   c   e   1
7   c   f   1
8   g   i   1
9   b   h   1
10  g   i   1

df.groupby(['0','1'], as_index=False).sum()

    0   1   2
0   a   d   10
1   b   b   2
2   b   h   8
3   c   e   4
4   c   f   4
5   g   i   2
```

Comment: Sorry if it took some time to reply. This actually worked! however I've run into a small problem, if there are any entries with a number (which pandas is reading as `int`) it won't filter. Say, instead of a -> d it goes 18 -> b or sometimes it may go from number to number like 15 -> 4.